# Word Choice: 'Like' or 'As'

Tags: word-choice

In this sentence, which would be the better word to use, 'like' or 'as'?

> "Chugging alcohol is like/as talking to God."

What would the difference be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Like

You can use *like* or *as* in comparisons, but they go with different grammatical follow-ups.

*Like* goes with nouns:

> Chugging alcohol is ***like* talking** to G-d.

*Similar* works the same way but ironically emphasizes the distinction instead of the similarity.

> Chugging alcohol is ***similar to* talking** to G-d [*implied* "but isn't the same thing"].

*As* goes with prepositional phrases and clauses:

> Chugging alcohol makes people feel ***as if* they were talking** to G-d.
>
> Chugging alcohol makes people feel ***as though* they were talking** to G-d.

There's also *as ~ as*, though, which takes nouns:

> Chugging alcohol is ***as good as* talking** to G-d.

although that also emphasizes that they are noticeably distinct things. It's just that they are considered equally good by the speaker.

Comment: There's also ([as pointed out here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88385/comparison-as-or-like)) a role for *as* when followed by nouns, but it's a different one meaning *in the role of*. 'Chugging alcohol is great as G-d' properly means, if you should happen to be G-d, chugging alcohol will be great for you. There's also *such as*, but that's used for listing examples.

Comment: *Like* can also take phrases as well, [though it's usually taken as less formal](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-or-like): *Chugging alcohol* [*is/feels/makes me feel*] *like I'm talking to G-d*. Really, those two words are both so basic that any prescriptivist rules start to get very messy and riddled with exceptions. The underlying problem is that *as* + a noun usually means something else and so sounds 'off' here.

Answer (score -2):

It is a comparison; one is looking for similarity.

Ergo, "like" applies, while "as" would be incorrect.

Comment: You use *as* for comparisons as well.

Comment: @lly: Not in this case.

Comment: Right, but that has nothing to do with its being a comparison.